# Should I ignore yellow warning for expo doctor --fix-dependencies

Tags: android, react-native, npm, expo

I installed the latest version of react-native elements `npm install @rneui/themed @rneui/base` which is not compatible with the latest `react-native-safe-area-context` so I installed `react-native-safe-area-context@3.4.1` So now the expo gives me following warning

```
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
 - @react-native-picker/picker - expected version: 2.4.0 - actual version installed: 2.4.2
 - react-native-safe-area-context - expected version: 4.2.4 - actual version installed: 3.4.1
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo doctor --fix-dependencies,
or install individual packages by running expo install [package-name ...]
```